# Using `snakemake --cluster` without SLURM

Tags: snakemake, qsub

In our working group, my colleagues and I sometimes let our jobs run on each others computers to better utilize our resources. Is there a way to use `snakemake --cluster` in this scenario without a "proper" cluster setup? Is there a `qsub` implementation that simply executes the supplied command on other computers via SSH? (Without requiring the target node to be part of a formal cluster?)

If I understand correctly, `snakemake --cluster` assumes the same file system to be mounted on all cluster nodes. This is partial true in our case, as our home directories are on NFS.

Comment: Not sure this exists.. But if you have root access to your machines, it might be worth setting up your own little slurm "cluster" among your colleagues. You could have one machine act as a controller and the others running slurmd daemons with low priority and resource restrictions to reserve some compute for the desktop user.

Comment: Would a slurm daemon detect that the machine is already in use by a local process (that was started outside of slurm)?

Comment: A priority level for the daemon and all of its spawned subprocesses can be set when starting the daemon. This should allow local processes to take priority, but I have never tested a setup like this. Here's a relevant question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533727/slurm-on-desktop-computers-how-to-prioritize-the-owner